# MediaElement and AAC stream support on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, streaming, audio-streaming, aac, icecast

According to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) the Windows Phone 7 supports the AAC encoded audio stream in the browser and via the `MediaElement API` as well. We have tested few the icecast streams (e.g. [this](http://62.44.1.26:8000/cro2-128aac)) it on our devices (e.g. HTC HD7 T9292, with latest updated - ver 7.0 (7392) ), but it does not work either in web browser or via API. The mp3 live stream works fine.

Any clues, why the AAC does not work, even the documentation says it should?
BR
SteN

Comment: Does it not work at all?  I'm assuming you've tested your AAC stream on other clients?  No error or anything?

Comment: Hi, we tested the API and AAC link in the IE browser. I tried to download the other client, but Marketplace is not working today:((

Comment: Hi, so far it looks there is support in Mango, but not in 7.0:((

Answer (score 1):

Icecast is not pure AAC, in 7.0 you need to strip out the icecast headers and metadata using a custom MediaStreamSource and then feed the raw AAC to the MediaElement.

It looks like from your comments that they may have added native icecast support to Mango.