# AAC Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, streaming, audio-streaming, aac, internet-radio

I have an online-radio which sending a AAC stream. So According to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) the Windows Phone 7 supports the AAC encoded audio stream via MediaElement API.

But this stream has a headers (icy-notice, icy-..., etc.) which should be deleted before. 
I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020995/mediaelement-and-aac-stream-support-on-windows-phone-7) post and how i understood i should implement MediaStreamSource before but i don't understand how implement GetAudioSample() and parsing each frame that sending online-radio.

Could you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Any news here? What did you do?

Comment: I implemented own MediaStreamSource. =)

Comment: Is it working on WP8?

Comment: Not at all. 
For WP8 I reimplemented it, because WP8 has a bit different API. I can't show my code but you can find examples in web easy.

Comment: Thanks, any links to guide me?

Comment: You can try to learn from this https://playerframework.codeplex.com/

Comment: And https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/MediaStreamSource-media-dfd55dff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this project http://shoutcastmss.codeplex.com/, there they have a custom implementation of MediaStreamSource that you may find useful.